# Subselect Query Improvement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How can I improve the SQL query below (SQL Server 2008)? I want to try to avoid sub-selects, and I'm using a couple of them to produce results like this

```
StateId        TotalCount      SFRCount        OtherCount
---------------------------------------------------------
AZ             102             50              52
CA             2931            2750            181
etc...

SELECT 
    StateId, 
    COUNT(*) AS TotalCount,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) AS Expr1 FROM Property AS P2
        WHERE (PropertyTypeId = 1) AND (StateId = P.StateId)) AS SFRCount,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) AS Expr1 FROM Property AS P3
        WHERE (PropertyTypeId <> 1) AND (StateId = P.StateId)) AS OtherCount
FROM Property AS P
GROUP BY StateId
HAVING (COUNT(*) > 99)
ORDER BY StateId
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This may work the same, hard to test without data

```
    SELECT 
        StateId, 
        COUNT(*) AS TotalCount,
        SUM(CASE WHEN PropertyTypeId = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as SFRCount,
        SUM(CASE WHEN PropertyTypeId <> 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as OtherCount
    FROM Property AS P
    GROUP BY StateId
    HAVING (COUNT(*) > 99)
    ORDER BY StateId
```

Comment: Your answer should have correct output, and in my experience `SUM(CASE...)` tends to be surprisingly fast compared to using inner selects.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I edited your answer to remove an extraneous comma after "OtherCount".

Answer (score 0):

Your alternative is a single self-join of `Property` using your `WHERE` conditions as a join parameter. The OtherCount can be derived by subtracting the `TotalCount - SFRCount` in a derived query.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative would be to use the PIVOT function like this:

```
SELECT StateID, [1] + [2] AS TotalCount, [1] AS SFRCount, [2] AS OtherCount
FROM Property
PIVOT ( COUNT(PropertyTypeID) 
        FOR PropertyTypeID IN ([1],[2])
        ) AS pvt
WHERE [1] + [2] > 99
```

You would need to add an entry for each property type which could be daunting but it is another alternative.  Scott has a great answer.

Answer (score 0):

If PropertyTypeId is not null then you could do this with a single join.   Count is faster than Sum.  But is Count plus Join faster than Sum.  The test case below mimics your data.  docSVsys has 800,000 rows and there are about 300 unique values for caseID.   The Count plus Join in this test case is slightly faster than the Sum.  But if I remove the with (nolock) then Sum is about 1/4 faster.   You would need to test with your data.

```
    select GETDATE()
    go;
    select caseID, COUNT(*) as Ttl, 
        SUM(CASE WHEN mimeType = 'message/rfc822' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as SFRCount,
        SUM(CASE WHEN mimeType <> 'message/rfc822' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as OtherCount,
        COUNT(*) - SUM(CASE WHEN mimeType = 'message/rfc822' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as OtherCount2
    from docSVsys with (nolock) 
    group by caseID
    having COUNT(*) > 1000
    select GETDATE()
    go;
    select docSVsys.caseID, COUNT(*) as Ttl
    , COUNT(primaryCount.sID) as priCount 
    , COUNT(*) -  COUNT(primaryCount.sID) as otherCount
    from docSVsys with (nolock) 
    left outer join docSVsys as primaryCount with (nolock) 
        on primaryCount.sID = docSVsys.sID
        and primaryCount.mimeType = 'message/rfc822'
    group by docSVsys.caseID
    having COUNT(*) > 1000
    select GETDATE()
    go;
```